# How to insert result function in raster created pyqgis3

Tags: pyqgis

I am doing a script, but I have a problem with the insertion of the result that my calculation function provided in my raster output that I created. Does anyone know how to insert the output result into a raster output that has been declared.

That's what I started to do:

```
class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

    #Declaration de nos shapes comme des variables text
    Vector_layer_of_communes = 'Vector_layer_of_communes'
    OUTPUT_raster = 'OUTPUT_raster'
    Commune_name='Commune_name'
    INSEE_code='INSEE_code'
    EPSG_code='EPSG_code'

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):

        #Parametrage des shapes dentree
        shape_commune = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.Vector_layer_of_communes, context)
        #Parametrage du resultat en fichier de sorti
        output_path_raster = self.parameterAsOutputLayer(parameters, self.OUTPUT_raster, context)
        attribut_INSEE_code = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.INSEE_code, context)
        attribut_Commune_name = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.Commune_name, context)
        attribut_EPSG_code = self.parameterAsString(parameters, self.EPSG_code, context)

        def recuperation_cadastre_commune(layer,INSEE_code,Commune_name,EPSG_code):

            rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'Cadastre_'+n_couche+'_'+c_insee, 'wms')
            output_path_raster=rlayer

            #My problem is here, how to insert this raster in my OUTPUT_raster created


        #Fonction de calcul du besoin
        recuperation_cadastre_commune(shape_commune,attribut_INSEE_code,attribut_Commune_name,attribut_EPSG_code)
        results = {}
        results[self.OUTPUT_raster] = output_path_raster
        return results#{}
```